# Set and select in mysql stored procedure does not work correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQl stored procedure which behaves abnormal and gives wrong output.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetVotes(IN postId INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE upVotes INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE downVotes INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE stars INT DEFAULT 0;

SET upVotes := ( SELECT count(upvote) FROM threadvote WHERE upvote = 1 AND postid = postId );

SET downVotes := (SELECT count(downvote) FROM threadvote WHERE downvote = 1 AND postid = postId );

SET stars := (SELECT count(starred) FROM threadvote WHERE starred = 1 AND postid = postId );

SELECT upVotes as numupvotes, downVotes as numdownvotes , stars as numstars;

END
```

Its such simple as cake still its eating up my time because it gives wrong output.
The SET statements sets variables with all counts of the rows in the table (i.e. it appears to ignore the where clause ).

Example Data:

```
itemid userid   postid upvote   downvote starred
9      15       9        1        0        0
12     16       9        1        0        1
13     15       7        1        0        0
14     15       8        1        0        1
15     16       7        1        0        1
16     16       8        0        1        0
17     16       11       0        1        0
18     15       11       0        1        0
```

Now `CALL GetVotes(8);` gives me:

```
numupvotes numdownvotes numstars
5          3            2
```

which should have been:

```
numupvotes numdownvotes numstars
1          1            1
```

Additionally DECLARE with @ symbol gives syntax error. e.g

```
DECLARE @upVotes INT DEFAULT 0;
```

gives syntax error.

Please let me know what is wrong here. 
Or am i missing some mysql server setting ?

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag because the syntax suggests MySQL.

Comment: maybe not have the input parameter with the same name as a field --- like `in_postid`  It seems clear that `AND postid = postId` is just evaluating to true.

Comment: Thanks Hogan. So its not case sensitive in MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

You have a collision problem with names.  Namely, `postid = postid` is almost always true.  Use prefixes to distinguish parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetVotes(IN in_postId INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE upVotes INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE downVotes INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE stars INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT up_Votes := SUM(upvote = 1), downvote := SUM(downvote = 1),
           stars := SUM(starred = 1)
    FROM threadvote tv
    WHERE tv.postid = in_postId;

    SELECT upVotes as numupvotes, downVotes as numdownvotes , stars as numstars;

END
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right about Name collision. I have worked with sql-server where it would work just fine. My Sql certainly have many syntax differences.

Comment: But your query still gives syntax error to me near the use of := along with Select statement. Although i am getting no error while using := operator with set statement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need variables, try this:

```
SELECT 
        SUM(upvote) numupvotes, 
        SUM(downvote) numdownvotes,
        SUM(starred) numstars
FROM threadvote t
WHERE t.postid = postId
```

Also to avoid naming conflict you'd better point table column name by preceding with table name (or by table alias)

Answer (score 0):

set the input parameter to a different name - like `in_postid`. It seems clear that `AND postid = postId` is just evaluating to true